# what is the jetty alternative for org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jetty, embedded-server

I am switching a Spring Boot application's server from Tomcat to Jetty. I am unable to find any Jetty alternative for the org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException exception. This exception exists in the tomcat-coyote dependency, but if I add it, Tomcat will handle the HTTP requests instead of Jetty.

I am also concerned about other exceptions that are not present in Jetty, such as ClientAbortException. How should I deal with these exceptions during the transition?

Comment: Why are you even catching/handling those exceptions? Spring Boot wraps them in other generic exceptions you should handle.

Comment: It's some legacy code i'm dealing with, which generic exception should i handle in this case

Comment: Without seeing the code that will be impossible to answer. When using `RestTemplate` you will have a `ClientException` of sorts.

Comment: these are mostly used here for handling stuff like "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
", if i handle multipartException Directly, will that also work with jetty

Comment: You should be handling the `MultipartException` (the wrapper from Spring) which will work regardless of the container.

Comment: Got your point,thank you
so similarly, if i have org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException
,i should handle IOException instead? (i'm new to this )

Comment: It depends, if you are unwrapping exceptions (like the multipart one) you should be handling the spring specific one. There is no rule of thumb here.